# Facebook graph FB.login connect dialog, cancel event

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using FB.login when user is not connected and everything seems fine, though when user clicks **cancel** on the fb connect dialog, it closes and I have to raise an event on my page on this cancel event (or at least redirect somewhere when the user hit cancel).

Searched and searched but couldn't find how to raise such event (I've tried to subscribe to "auth.cancel" but it just doesn't work).
Any ideas?

Comment: It's an interesting question, "auth.statusChange" is not even triggered if user cancels when authorizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user cancels the login he is redirected to your page with the following GET parameters:

1. error_reason=user_denied
2. error=access_denied
3. error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.

EDIT:

In JS SDK, as stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/):

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
     if (response.authResponse) {
         console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
         FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
         });
     } else {
         console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
     }
 });
```

Comment: The thing is I open with FB.login method and hence when user clicks cancel it wont redirect nowhere, it would just close the login window and show my site page.

Comment: maybe you also have idea on this other question I've added: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074504/control-fb-login-dialog-image