# control fb.login dialog image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was wondering how can I control the image on the connect dialog? I get some random image from my main page (in very bad quality), and not the profile image of the facebook app.
I've tried setting the og:image meta tag on the main page of my website but it wont use it.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app settings, under „auth dialog”, edit the logo.